# Discriminator column not set in newly persisted entity

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have a base class entity that looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "IDTYPE",
    discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING,
    length = 12)
public class ProtoObject implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String              idtype;

  // more columns
```

I have a number of sub-classes of this that I build and persist.  However I have found that even though **idtype** column gets set to what I would expect in the data base (checking with a separate DB browser tool) the Java objects **idtype** *property* does not get set for those object that the EntityManager has in its cache.

If I do a find of objects through the EntityManager, the most recently persisted objects appear to have **idtype** blank!  If I close the application and re-open it the data appears OK.

This is a JSF 2 application using EclipseLink 2.3.2.v20111125-r1046.

Is this a known problem and can anyone suggest a work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the attribute when you created the object to reflect what you wanted pushed to the database.  You need to set the field to keep it consistent in the cache as JPA Entities are treated as regular java objects and won't fix things for you.  Or after persist you can flush the changes them refresh the object to have the field populated with what is in the DB

Comment: You also need to mark the idtype attribute as insertable=false, updateable=false or it will conflict with the inheritance discriminator field mapping.

Comment: Interesting.  Because the column does get set when it is pushed to the data base, I assumed that the property should also be set.  It gets the value of the Java class name.  This is different from the way the ID field works, and I hadn't seen that in any example code.   THanks for the note.

Comment: JPA allows accessing the field in queries using they TYPE key word, so there shouldn't be much need for the field to be mapped.  If this isn't enough, it can be set in an event such as PrePersist so it is consistent in the cache.  "select p from Project p where TYPE(p) in(LargeProject, SmallProject)"

Comment: I developed the need for the column to be mapped because I could not figure out how else to do a Criteria Query where the DiscriminatorColumn's value was referenced in the WHERE clause.  The EclipseLink source generator doesn't create a reference for that column unless I do this.

Comment: Criteria API's Join has the type() method that can be used to access this field.  You could also add a native EclipseLink query key for the database field rather than a mapping to access the field within queries, but the mapping will work fine with the caveat mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can update cache after persisting:

```
    this.entityManager.persist(protoObject);
    this.entityManager.flush();
    this.entityManager.refresh(protoObject);
```